# In Monopoly, Can I mortgage the property I land on in order raise sufficient funds for its purchase?

Tags: monopoly

While discussing [What happens if the auction winner cannot pay his/her bid?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/39455/in-monopoly-what-happens-if-the-auction-winner-cannot-pay-his-her-bid) I concluded that the winning bidder cannot use the mortgage value of the property being auctioned to fund his bid.
Does the person landing on a property have the right to mortgage this property in order to buy it?

The [official rules state](http://www.tmk.edu.ee/~creature/monopoly/download/official_rules_gathering/official_tournament_kit_tournament_guide.pdf)

> Buying Property Whenever a player lands on an
>   unowned property, the player may buy that property from
>   the Bank at its printed price. The player receives the Title
>   Deed card showing ownership and places it **face up** in
>   front of him/her. If he/she does not wish to buy the
>   property, it is sold at auction by the Banker to the highest
>   bidder. The buyer pays to the Bank the amount of the **bid**
>   in cash and receives the Title Deed card for that property.
>   Any player, including the one who declined the option of
>   buying it at the printed price, may bid. Bidding may start
>   at any price.

The "face up" terminology seems to indicate that the property will not be in a mortgaged state at time of purchase.

Comment: Excellent! I see you are a quick study.

Comment: Note this question arose while discussing the related question: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/39455/in-monopoly-what-happens-if-the-auction-winner-cannot-pay-his-her-bid

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the rules you posted link to.

> The player who mortgages property
>   retains possession of it and no other player may secure it
>   by lifting the mortgage from the Bank.

If a player **retains** possession, they must **have** possession of it in first place.  So it can't be mortgaged before purchase.